# GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV (sklearn): TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to use `GridSearchCV` and `RandomizedSearchCV` to find the best parameters for two unsupervised learning algorithms (for novelty detection), namely, `OneClassSVM` and `LocalOutlierFactor` both by [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org).

Below is the function that I wrote (made modifications to this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_randomized_search.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-randomized-search-py)):

```
def gridsearch(clf, param_dist_rand, param_grid_exhaustive, X):


    def report(results, n_top=3):
       for i in range(1, n_top + 1):
           candidates = np.flatnonzero(results['rank_test_score'] == i)
           for candidate in candidates:
               print("Model with rank: {0}".format(i))
               print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.3f})".format(
                results['mean_test_score'][candidate],
                results['std_test_score'][candidate]))
               print("Parameters: {0}".format(results['params'][candidate]))
               print("")

     n_iter_search = 20
     random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, 
     param_distributions=param_dist_rand, n_iter=n_iter_search, cv=5, 
     error_score=np.NaN, scoring='accuracy')

      start = time()
      random_search.fit(X)
      print("RandomizedSearchCV took %.2f seconds for %d candidates"
      " parameter settings." % ((time() - start), n_iter_search))
      report(random_search.cv_results_)


      grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid_exhaustive, 
      cv=5, error_score=np.NaN, scoring='accuracy')
      start = time()
      grid_search.fit(X)

      print("GridSearchCV took %.2f seconds for %d candidate parameter 
      settings."
      % (time() - start, len(grid_search.cv_results_['params'])))
      report(grid_search.cv_results_)
```

To test the function above I have the following code:

```
X, W = train_test_split(all_data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
clf_lof = LocalOutlierFactor(novelty=True, contamination='auto')
lof_param_dist_rand = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(6, 101, 1), 'leaf_size': 
                      np.arange(30, 101, 10)}
lof_param_grid_exhaustive = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(6, 101, 1), 
                           'leaf_size': np.arange(30, 101, 10)}
gridsearch(clf=clf_lof, param_dist_rand=lof_param_dist_rand, 
param_grid_exhaustive=lof_param_grid_exhaustive, X=X)


clf_svm = svm.OneClassSVM()
svm_param_dist_rand = {'nu': np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.01), 'kernel': ['rbf', 
                     'linear','poly','sigmoid'], 'degree': np.arange(0, 7, 
                      1), 'gamma': scipy.stats.expon(scale=.1),}
svm_param_grid_exhaustive = {'nu': np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.01), 'kernel': 
                            ['rbf', 'linear','poly','sigmoid'], 'degree': 
                            np.arange(0, 7, 1), 'gamma': 0.25}
gridsearch(clf=clf_svm, param_dist_rand=svm_param_dist_rand, 
param_grid_exhaustive=svm_param_grid_exhaustive, X=X)
```

Initially, I did not include set the `scoring` parameter for both `GridSearch` methods and I got this error:

```
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method.
```

I then added `scoring='accuracy'` since I want to use the test accuracy to judge the performance of the different model configurations. Now I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
```

I do not have labels since I have data from one class and none from counter classes so I do not know how to go about this error. Additionally, I looked at what as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942502/what-is-passthrough-scorer-and-how-can-i-change-scorers-in-gridsearchcv-sklear) but it did not help me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
As per @FChm suggestion of providing sample data, please find the sample `.csv` data file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7eorvk1twzlopmu/SampleData.csv?dl=0). A short description of the file:
Consists of four columns of features (PCA generated) that I feed into my models.

Comment: People may be more likely to help if you provide a link to some example data.

Comment: @FChm I have added a file with the sample data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think the discussion following this question might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611038/grid-search-for-hyperparameter-evaluation-of-clustering-in-scikit-learn 
In short, it is not a very intuitive choice to use GridSearchCV without y_true, because you basically do not need any cross validation anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MaximeKan. I have not found an option of using GridSearch without CV. Still searching though.

Comment: There is a way suggested here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636370/scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-without-cross-validation-unsupervised-learning/44661188) but it's no longer applicable, I tried it.

Comment: @TMK a GridSearch without CV is basically just one or several for loops. You can find one example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936518/how-do-i-automate-the-number-of-clusters/54937191#54937191